# django development server quitting

Tags: python, django, django-views

When I attempt to access particular pages of my application on the django development server, the server suddenly quits with no error message, leaving the browser with a "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)"

What kind of thing could I have done in the code that would cause the development server to suddenly quit with no error messages?

The GET request that triggers the server to quit is not logged. For example, after starting the server and attempting a GET of one of the problem pages, my command line looks like this:

```
(mysite)01:25 PM benjamin ~/projects/mysite $ runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
(mysite)01:28 PM benjamin ~/projects/mysite $
```

I'm running django 1.3.3 in a virtualenv using Python 2.6

Comment: No idea what could cause this but I would suggest creating a new virtualenv with django1.4 and seeing if you have the same problem as a workaround.

Comment: I upgraded to django1.4 in the same virtualenv, and now it just prints "Bus error" before quitting out.

Comment: It seems to occur while loading a template

Comment: So confusing, it seems to happen when I try to render a template with a particular object in the context. Perhaps it is related to the database.

Comment: It happens when processing an 'extends' on a template':w

Comment: Can you post the template? Does running the development server of a new django project work ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

I found this because I was encountering a similar problem. It turned out I was running out of memory. Figured I would mention it on the off chance that it helps someone.

Comment: This answer is better suited to be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The bus error can happen when you're trying to extend a template with another template that has *the same filename and relative path*.

#### Example

Let's say you want to use your own `poll.html` template for the `voting` app, but to reuse as much as possible, you extend from the *original* poll.html:

```
<!-- myapp/templates/voting/poll.html -->
{% extends 'voting/poll.html' %}
<!-- Trying to extend from 'voting/templates/voting/poll.html' -->
...
```

This will give you the bus error, because the template is extending "itself", even though that's not what you're trying to do.

Your own `voting/poll.html` is shadowing the original `poll.html` from the voting app, which will never be found

```
myproject/myapp/templates/voting/poll.html
myproject/voting/templates/voting/poll.html <-- you cannot extend from this
```

I haven't found a general solution to this, but I ran into the problem trying to customize the admin app's `index.html` and for that there is a solution (See below).

#### Customizing the "admin" app

I got the "bus error" when trying to customize the `index.html` in the admin app, and extending from the original `admin/index.html`. The solution to that specific problem is described here: [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20790068/118608) – you name your own `admin/index.html` something else, in order to extend from the original `admin/index.html`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900187/django-template-inheritance-causes-a-bus-error