# Custom changelist_form and list_editable in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I wanted to introduce custom editable field in Django Admin list view. I wanted to do something very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233551/custom-list-editable-field-in-django-admin-change-list-which-doesnt-correspond).

The problem that I am facing is that Django requires that all fields from `list_editable` must be fields in a model.

```
class SomeModel(Model):
   ...

class SomeModelChangeListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
    name = forms.CharField()

class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return SomeModelForm

    list_display = ['name']
    list_editable = ['name']
```

So if there is no `name` field on model it doesn't work, validation fails.

**Edit**: The specific validation error I am getting:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   'SomeModelAdmin.list_editable' refers to a field, 'name', not
>   defined on SomeModel.

You can see this place in sources: [Django sources](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/admin/validation.py#L329).

Comment: What validation error do you get? Is `name` in `list_display` and not in `list_display_links` (either explicitly or by default)?

Comment: @mfcovington I added to question for visibility

Comment: Your question seems to be covered by Peter's answer to the other question. As he says, if the only field you want to edit is not a model field, then it gets complicated. He then gives a couple of suggestions.

Comment: @Alasdair I couldn't make any of them work. If you can provide specifics in an answer I would gladly accept it. I can't even understand how can it work because in Django sources there is very straightforward check for this case that fails.

Comment: In addition to adding a method as Schuyler answered, the key is to NOT put `name` in `list_editable`.  In Peter's answer in the linked question, he mentions that there must be at least one field in the list_editable.  That is true, however, to make the custom field you describe work it must NOT be in `list_editable`.

Comment: The error message is very self-explanatory. You don't have a field called `name` on your `SomeModel`.

Comment: @Bobort please read carefully (also check the linked question), I wanted to have a custom editable field in the form that doesn't exist on model. I know it is not on model and I don't want it to be on model. Anyway this is 7 yo question, I don't even remember all the details why I needed it back then.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some clarification to answer by @kagronick

Add to `SomeModelAdmin`

```
def name(self, obj=None):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this the other day. It turns out simply having a variable or a method like

```
def name(self):
   pass
```

makes this go away.