# Django model layout with multiple columns

Tags: django, django-grappelli

My admin page for a specific model has two stackedInlines.  Currently they display one under the other.  I would like them to display side by side so The page would look like this (don't have enough reputation to embed the image :[ )

[image]

Any easy way to go about this without having to write my own admin page?

If that's the only solution, how exactly would I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override Django admin template for each app in your project.

you just have too create same folder as your app in template directory and overriding html.

[How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)

You can add CSS/Javascript to admin page by defining class Media.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the admin template to accomplish this. See roshan's answer for more info.