# Change zinnia app name to Blog Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, zinnia

[image]

I am using zinnia to create a blog application in my website using django(1.6.5). But as in image my app name is showing as "Zinnia" in the django admin page which i would like to change as "Blog". Could some one explain me how i could do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can try like:

```
class Zinnia(models.Model):
        ....
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'Blog'
```

**update:**

well, from django source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html#L15

You can simply override django admin's index page to change app name in adminsite.(check: [how to override admin template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)). Do this (templates/admin/index.html):

```
{% if app_list %}
    {% for app in app_list %}
        <div class="app-{{ app.app_label }} module">
        <table>
        <caption>
            {% if app.name == 'Zinnia' %}
            <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section" title="{% blocktrans with name=app.name %}Models in the Blog application{% endblocktrans %}"> Blog </a>
        </caption>
        {% for model in app.models %}

 ....
```

Comment: zinnia.entry: 'categories' has an m2m relation with model zinnia.Category, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

Comment: well you have to use syncdb(if you don't have database or drop database and recreate) or migrate(if have an existing database and don't want to drop it, and have to south in that case: http://south.aeracode.org/) to solve this issue :)

Comment: First of all zinnia is not a model. its a project. http://django-blog-zinnia.com/.

Comment: @itsme well, I have updated my answer. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, But it changes only the dashboard right?. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can read what is app name and how to give  [app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#app-label)

You have to change the `model.py` yourself for what you want to achieve. I assume that your zinna app located in site-packages.

i.e, see this link [django-blog-zinna](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/0f531dfcf181d5641c01e83397f92ee415b126e5/zinnia/models_bases/entry.py#L179)

```
app_label = 'Blog'
```

And edit yourself, i havn't checked that but it may encounter error and you have to clear yourself