# Adding link to the admin index page in django

Tags: django, django-templates

How can a page be linked to the admin page of django?
I have tried changing the base.html page but it is getting reflected to all the html pages of the admin. Can this be linked just to the index page of admin where all the app are listed.

Comment: removing superfluous content

Answer (score 5):

You have to **override** Django *admin index.html* page

**First step:**

Create new file in your templates folder call it '*index.html*' for example.
For example file path will be like: '*YOUR_PROJECT/templates/admin/index.html*' and copy the following code:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>YOUR EXTRA CODE</h1>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Second step:**

Create new file in YOUR_MAIN_PROJECT folder -alongside *settings.py*- call it *admin.py* and copy the following code:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite


class CustomAdmin(AdminSite):
    index_template = 'admin/base_site.html'


custom_admin_site = CustomAdmin(name='admin')
```

**Third step:**

In YOUR_APP *admin.py* file put the following code:

```
from YOUR_MAIN_PROJECT.admin import custom_admin_site
from .models import YOUR_MODEL_1, YOUR_MODEL_2

custom_admin_site.register(YOUR_MODEL_1)
custom_admin_site.register(YOUR_MODEL_2)
```

I hope this helps, your respond is appreciated

Comment: 2nd and 3rd steps can be omitted if you put your extended template in `PROJECT_ROOT/MYAPP/templates/admin/index.html` and MYAPP is in `INSTALLED_APPS` and you have `"APP_DIRS": True` in the `TEMPLATES` setting in `settings.py`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin panel</a>
```

But you have to have to add admin.site.urls in your URLS.py

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

But if you are trying to render admin site in one of your sites (let's say index):

```
url(r'', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i don't want to link the admin page to my html page. Insetad, i want to access my html page from the admin.

Comment: So you have to edit your templates from contrib.admin.
If you're using virtualnenv, it should be in `your_env/local/lib/python_version/django/contrib/admin/templates`

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński: Instead of modifying the template in the library location, it is better to copy it into your project and modify it. That way, you don't lose it if Django is upgraded or reinstalled.

Comment: Correct ;) Thought it was obvious ;)

Answer (score 0):

Reference :
[How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates/29997719#29997719)

You can customize the index template as:

```
# urls.py
...
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.index_template = 'admin/my_custom_index.html'
admin.autodiscover()
```

and place your template in /templates/admin/my_custom_index.html

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{block.super}}
    <div>
        <h1>Others</h1>
        <a href="/v1/my_new_link/">A new link menu</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```