# How can I implement Semantic-UI with Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, semantic-ui

I am actually learning **django** and I've been working on their [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/). So far, everything looks great but unfortunately I was trying to change the admin panel look using [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/). I don't want to add / remove anything (forms / text / etc) but change its aspect. Can anybody give me some hints on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override django default Admin templates to implement sementic-ui in it. 
Follow [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates) to learn how to override django default templates.