# Adding links and buttons on django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to add some external links and buttons on the django admin page?
I am trying to add link of my web page on the django-admin login page and unable to do so.

Answer (score 6):

In order to override admin login page, you need to provide custom ['templates/admin/login.html'](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html) file

Check this answer to find the proper template file location and settings - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997719/46548

Comment: Also, be careful to lookup the documentation for overriding the admin page for the correct version of Django. This answer on the same page could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586068/1526703