# Custom Admin Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am try create a personal login screen template, but not work.

https://github.com/rg3915/custom-admin

I configure the settings:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates_admin')],
```

Create the folders e templates

https://github.com/rg3915/custom-admin/tree/master/myproject/core/templates_admin/admin

But not work.

Comment: What does "not work" entail? errors? invalid results? What *does* happen?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29997719/3853907) for details on overriding admin templates in newer Django distributions (1.8+)

Comment: @Sayse Dont load the template customized.

Comment: @IanPrice this answer not work. See my refactor [GitHub](https://github.com/rg3915/custom-admin) again, please.

Comment: Resolved: the folders is `templates/admin/login.html`. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the corrent path so that the template loader finds your custom template should be `admin/login.html`, not `admin/core/login.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates 
informs that simply create the folder templates/admin/ inner the app, in my case myproject/core/

In this case , the order of the apps matter .

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # my apps
    'myproject.core',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
```