# Adding new pages to Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I am looking for information on how to add entirely new pages to the django admin interface. I need to add a view that allows admins to change the contents of an existing text file. This view needs to exist within the existing django admin app. I am using django 1.9.

I found information on extending existing pages, but not adding entirely new pages. Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates

Comment: Have a look at the docs on [`get_urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls).

Comment: @Alasdair That was it. Took me a hot minute to find it. Django docs are great, but there is alot of info to sift through!

Comment: @mstagg Great, glad it helped. Django docs are good, but it can be tricky if you don't know exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've written your view, you can include it in the admin by overriding [`get_urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls).

An alternative is to override the `AdminSite` class, which also has a [`get_urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) method. However this will require changing more code if you are not already using a custom `AdminSite` subclass.