# Can I use the django debug_toolbar on the admin pages?

Tags: django, requirejs, admin

**(Note:  the answer is a qualified 'yes' - it should work if not for my requirejs configuration issue - see my update at the end)**

I'm looking into customizing the admin for a number of Models where savvy end-users are expected to do the maintenance.

I've seen a number of SO questions, such as [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates/29997719#29997719), on how to achieve this.

I expect that knowing which template files are being used by the admin at any particular point is key to customizing efficiently.  So, I re-enabled the Django Debug Toolbar (hopefully wo requirejs side-effects this time).

The Django Debug Toolbar works and shows up in my apps' pages.  But it doesn't show up on the admin pages.  Is that to be expected?

[image]

Django (1.8.11)
django-debug-toolbar (1.4)

## Why it's not working/Update:

I think I know what is happening.  When looking at Firebug to see what CSS is involved with an admin page, I noticed that it was requesting debug toolbar CSS:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css
```

Which got me to think of requireJS incompatibility again.  Sure enough, in the console, I see this error.

**TypeError: $ is undefined
http://localhost:8000/static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js
Line 297**

**So, again a requireJS-DJT glitch.**

FYI, my Debug toolbar workaround for requireJS was (from https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/605):

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
"JQUERY_URL": None,
```

}

and in my app's base template:

(this is the part that is missing from the admin pages)

```
{% block requirejs %}

//as per DJDT recommendations, make sure jquery loads before requireJS
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/websec/external/jquery-2.1.1.min"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}websec/external/require.js"></script>
<script>
//defines the requirejs configuration in general.
{% include "websec/requirejs_config.html" %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's generally considered bad practice to use the built-in admin backend for end-users.

Try checking foy `<body></body>` tags in the pages.  Without these it will not load.

Then try adding INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1') in settings.py

To make it ONLY load for users inside the admin panel, you could add a tag to your custom admin pages and change `settings.DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG['INSERT_BEFORE']`
Docs: [here](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#toolbar-options)

Last to force it to show everywhere, you can try adding this to the settings file:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
    return True
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK" : show_toolbar,
}
```

to stop debug toolbar from checking if it should appear or not, it always will Only use for testing/development purposes.  All other users can see it as well.

Documentation: [here](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: Nope, no effect.  Restarted django and DEBUG is True, but no change.

Comment: Yes, I know this is not a normal practice.  But the context is that it a VM-based app, so the user on-site has to be able to configure at least some of it via the admin.  And it would be nice if the look & feel wasn't totally different in that case.  Anyway, really just having a look at it, I may decide to stick with accepted wisdom and write custom pages.

Comment: Try INSERT_BEFORE setting with a custom tag only on the admin pages

Comment: <body> tags are there in admin pages.  INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1') had no effect either.  I did not try INSERT_BEFORE.  I'll hold off on Django Debug Toolbar, in admin, for now.  The **site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin** directory doesn't have that much stuff in it and it seems fairly self-explanatory so I may not need the Toolbar to find my way after all.

Comment: You can actually get a package to change the look of the admin to make it nicer.  I like suit personally.  And I believe you can customize what appears on the first login screen extensively with admin.py

Comment: Also, I have turned Django Toolbar off so many times because of requireJS problems that I don't want to spend too much time trying to make it work in this context.  But thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem, INSERT_BEFORE would normally work to put it on custom admin pages like that only.

Answer (score 0):

A quick overview over what I had to do to get debug_toolbar and admin working together.

You want to load jquery on its own, even though requireJS is configured to handle it as well.

From https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/605 :

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
"JQUERY_URL": None,
```

}

Now, set up the admin to load jquery outside of requireJS, so debug toolbar can find it:

I was planning to customize that admin anyway, so no big deal creating a base_site.html override.

**/myproj/templates/admin/base_site.html**

```
{% block extrahead %}
***************         add this (with proper path)   ************************
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}websec/external/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
*******************************************************************
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}websec/external/require.js"></script>
<script>
{% include "websec/requirejs_config.html" %}
require(['bootstrap'], function(bootstrap){
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is similar to what I had to do to my site's ancestor template to get debug_toolbar and requireJS to cohabit:

**/myproj/templates/websec/__base.html**

```
{% block requirejs %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/websec/external/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}websec/external/require.js"></script>
<script>
//defines the requirejs configuration in general.
{% include "websec/requirejs_config.html" %}
</script>
{% endblock requirejs %}
```

Unrelated, but a nice hack to get rid of debug_toolbar during unit testing:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    #... more stuff


    'debug_toolbar',

    'myapp',
    'djcelery',
    'crispy_forms',
)

#hack, but debug toolbar totally collapses performance on some tests
pgm = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
if pgm.startswith("test") or pgm.startswith("nosetests"):

    li = [app for app in INSTALLED_APPS if not app == "debug_toolbar"]
    INSTALLED_APPS = tuple(li)
```