# Extend django admin template

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.10

I'm trying to add a custom button in change_list django admin page next to the add object in the top of the page.

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} 
{% load i18n %} 
{% block object-tools-items %}
{{ block.super }}
<li>
    <button class="" href="...">Click Here!</button>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

I followed a lot of tutorials but with no success.
I have `'APP_DIRS': True,` in my settings.py and my project is like:

```
project/
    app/
        templates/
            change_list.html
            custom_template.html
```

The `custom_template.html` is an Action in change_list, and it works.
Am i missing something?

**EDIT:**

Already tried:

**project/app/templates/admin/change_list.html** **project/app/templates/app/admin/change_list.html**

Didn't work either.

Comment: Based on this question, it looks like you forgot to specify the app name in the extend tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change_list.html override file lives in this location:

**project/app/templates/admin/app/change_list.html**

You almost got it . :)

Also u may use django-debug-toolbar and get the actual templates that were uploaded at the browser side.

Answer (score 1):

Change you template location to
project/templates/admin/change_list.html

In template 'change_list.html' write

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">My custom Admin</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

and in setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
}]
```