# Sort Columns in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I know I should put up some code with what I've tried but I don't know where to start.

In Django admin I can display data so that it can be sorted by the user using:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['field1', 'field2']
    ordering = ['field2','field1']
```

Within the admin site, users will be able to click the top of the column and reorder on that column.

I want to replicate this functionality in an non-admin screen.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approaches available:

1. Import and modify the admin templates to use their sortable functionality. [This answer covers the basics very well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586068/1293222), but the ModelAdmin [class has a lot of functionality,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin) which you may or may not actually need. You can start from the [admin templates more generally](https://github.com/django/django/tree/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/contrib/admindocs/templates/admin_doc) if you want to go down that route.
2. Use an external library to manage in the templates.

I find the latter approach is actually easier, faster and more easily extensible.  I have just implemented this in a project using [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html), which takes a couple of minutes, assuming you already have a table.