# how to implement custom script into django in admin page? python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I know that I am allowed to add customized JS into django admin BUT can I just add something like `<script>var a = 'b';</script>` into django admin?

Now I am using something like

```
meta Media:
     js = ['/site_media/choice.js']
```

the reason I dont want to use the above is, I have a script which is like the above and the script will run differently in different admin model pages.

for example in the above `choice.js` I have a function `run()`

in model admin A I will want this page to use `run('abc')` but in model admin B I want this page to use `run('eee')`

if adding js instead of just typing out script, that means I will have to create quite a lot `js`

Can someone give me a hand of this? (currently using django 1.10.5)

Edited: Sorry my bad, I did try using the template first and few other ways but none worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)

Comment: @e4c5 tried that already, before I posted this :(

Comment: then you should explain that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = []
        js = ['sites/javascriptfile.js']
```

It is the Correct code to add js files or css files in django admin
just check the static path in `settings.py` file and path should be relative to static path.

Ok i Got it, you can check Url in javascript function
if it is for 'abc' you can run run('abc') in javascript if condition and else another one.

You can check url by

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("add") > -1) {
       // This is Add Page
       run('abc')
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("change") > -1) {
       // This is Change Page
       run('def')
    }
});
```

There are many more methods to check URL.

Comment: this is not what I meant