# How to redirect an admin user to redirect to the index page after logout from the default admin site in django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using Django's default admin dashboard for the landing page for an admin. I want to redirect the admin from the default Django admin site to the index page-(which is the homepage for all -users). How Can I do that?

Comment: See first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721363/overriding-the-logout-link-in-django-admin. I would suggest his 2nd solution

Answer (score 0):

### Do this configuration in settings.py

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'url name to redirect'
```

## ===== example =====

`This configuration redirect on home page after successfully logout form admin panel`

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/index/'
```

Comment: I tried this. But while logout from default Django admin dashboard, it is not redirecting to the desired page (index page )