# Admin InlineForm add links to Detail Page of the Inline Model and add custom javascript

Tags: django, django-admin

1. In Admin for InlineForm there is a link that goes to the website, be default the text is (View on site).
2. I want to add a similar link that goes to that model(that is inline) Detail Edit Page.
3. Insert a JavaScript script in one of the Edit/Details Model Page in Admin

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding JS and CSS to a models list_view and form_view pages are easy.
Write a class Media inside the admin class for the respective model.

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("css/mycss.css",)
        }
        js = ("js/my_js.js",)
```

Place the javascript file inside /yourapp/static/yourapp/js/my_js.js
and css inside /yourapp/static/yourapp/css/mycss.css

Comment: it is possible to add the link without Javascript ? how can css and javascript overwrite at all admin level the admin css

Comment: you can extend the admin templates check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates