# How can I integrate a bootstrap theme on admin side in python django 2.0?

Tags: django, admin, bootstrap-themes

I am developing a website with front-end and back-end in python django 2.0. I have integrated bootstrap theme on front-end and now I want to integrate [bootstrap theme](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_4/) on admin side. How can I add static files in admin templates. Can you guide me to integrate theme in admin side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)