# Django admin customization (without using themes like jet,suit)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I wish to do some Django admin customization, on which I require the filter panel to be placed at top of the page. Can we also update the other templates as well in some fashion? I have read the official docs for Django admin, but I am unable to implement as I am new to Django and frontend.

Comment: We really can't do much if you don't give us any code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can override and extend the default Django admin template files, and do any sort of changes to the UI, by writing your own admin template files.

As you know, there are several admin themes available for Django, you can go through them, and refer to how these themes are implemented (reading their code) and try making up one for your own as per your needs.

You can read about overriding Django templates -

- Already answered question - [How to Override and extend basic django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)
- Django Documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

You can also refer to the following directory on GitHub, which contains all the original Django admin template files, which you can override/extend - https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin