# Why can't I override the Django Admin template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-settings

I can't change my Django admin template. I have followed the instructions from the Django documentation, and I have already checked StackOverflow questions.

I have already made `/templates/admin/my_app/`, and changed `base_site.html` in `/templates/admin/my_app/base_site.html`

## settings.py:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

## base_site.html:

```
#base_site.html
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('NEW TITLE') }}{% 
endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ 
site_header|default:_('NEW TITLE') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

## File Structure:

```
my_project
└── my_project
    └── templates
        └── admin
           └── my_app
                └── base_site.html
```

Why can't I override the Django Admin template?

Comment: Try to refresh page by Ctrl+F5

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base_site.html should be placed in /templates/admin folder itself as shown below:

`/templates/admin/base_site.html` instead of `/templates/admin/my_app/base_site.html`

Comment: I thought I had tried them all, this finally solved it. I am using Django 2.2, for the records, and no other SO answer seemed to solve it, nor the 2.2 Django Docs which suggested exactly the OP structure.

Answer (score 1):

`base_site.html` can be automatically overridden only in `/templates/admin/` but not in `/templates/admin/<app>/` and `/templates/admin/<app>/<model>/`.

According to my experiments and [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model), the django admin templates in [django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin) in your virtual environment below can be automatically overridden all in `/templates/admin/`, `/templates/admin/<app>/` and `/templates/admin/<app>/<model>/`. *`app_index.html` is not meaningful to override in `/templates/admin/<app>/<model>/`:

```
actions.html  
app_index.html # *Not meaningful to override in `/templates/admin/<app>/<model>/`  
change_form.html  
change_form_object_tools.html  
change_list.html  
change_list_object_tools.html  
change_list_results.html  
date_hierarchy.html  
delete_confirmation.html
delete_selected_confirmation.html
object_history.html  
pagination.html  
popup_response.html  
prepopulated_fields_js.html  
search_form.html  
submit_line.html
```

And according to my experiments, the django admin templates in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/` in your virtual environment below can be automatically overridden only in `/templates/admin/`:

```
app_list.html
base.html
base_site.html
filter.html
index.html
login.html
nav_sidebar.html
```

And according to my experiments, the django admin templates in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/` in your virtual environment below can be automatically overridden only in `/templates/admin/auth/user/`:

```
add_form.html
change_password.html
```

And according to my experiments, the django admin templates in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/` in your virtual environment below can be automatically overridden only in `/templates/admin/edit_inline/`:

```
stacked.html
tabular.html
```

And according to my experiments, the django admin templates in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/` in your virtual environment below can be automatically overridden only in `/templates/admin/includes/`:

```
fieldset.html
object_delete_summary.html
```

And according to my experiments, the django admin templates in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/` in your virtual environment below can be manually overridden under `/templates/*`:

```
clearable_file_input.html
foreign_key_raw_id.html
many_to_many_raw_id.html
radio.html
related_widget_wrapper.html
split_datetime.html
url.html
```

Comment: I don't know why, just works in exactly that way your describe. I'm using Django 4.2