# Django channels in django admin

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-admin, django-channels

I would like to implement websocket chats inside of Django admin page. I have not found any information, if it is possible to do so?

I need some ideas to start from, maybe there are some tutorials on the topic? Or may it be completely impossible to do?

Comment: Have you considered simply embedding a chat widget instead? Trust me a good chat setup is very complicated, doubly so in a framework that's not built for websockets.

Comment: It's not impossible. You need to override Django admin templates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates

Comment: Have you considered Django channel?