# How to close the Django admin editable popup on clicking "Save" button

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I am having a link on the parent admin page. When I clicks on the link, an editable `django admin popup` page opens. After updating the details, When I clicks on the `Save` button, details are saved. But the requirement is to `close` that popup after clicking on `Save` button.

My editable admin Django model looks like below

```
@admin.register(SellOwnership)
class SellOwnershipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

      list_display = ("sell", "owner", "amount")
      list_editable = ("amount")
```

Kindle advise how to achieve to close the popup while clicking on `save` button. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Yes, the problem solved. We can override the admin interface along with few js tweaks. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve your intended functionality without overriding the `Django Admin Interface`.

The latter seems like the only possible way around this, you should see the answers here on how you can go about doing this for your case- [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)