# Adding an element that is not part of a model to Django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add a date that displays at the top of every page in Django admin but I haven't been able to find any documentation that discusses this. It needs to be a date that populates based on a script that says when the data was last pulled. Would anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586068/4151233 and the Django documentation. It describes how you can override/extend the Django template.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new field to your model last_edit_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) and it will be automatically store date and time of last edit [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)

Comment: I don't need it as part of a model. I just need it to be in the top corner of every page.

Comment: but from where you will get date when the data was last pulled? from model?

Answer (score 0):

in your settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'yourapphere', # your app here
    'django.contrib.admin',  # the admin here
    ...
]
```

in yourapp/templates/admin/base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}


{% block nav-global %}
    
    // your html and js here to make your clock
    
{% endblock %}
```