# Displaying DynamoDB data in Django admin panel

Tags: django, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I want to show data from DynamoDB on the Django admin panel page. I have tried PynamoDB to create the model and register it with the admin panel.

I am facing the following two issues:

1. Getting only attribute 'id' instead of all attributes from the DynamoDB table. I have confirmed this issue while fetching attribute_definitions from the DynamoDB table using boto3.

   attribute_definitions = table_name.attribute_definitions
2. The second issue I am facing is that I get errors while registering the created Model(by using PynamoDB) with the admin panel. I get the issue

> "TypeError: 'MetaModel' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 1):

you can pass this data to admin template using this method
`changelist_view`

Ex:

```
class DynmoDbAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        get data from dynamodb
        add this data to extra_context
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

after that
you need to extend admin template
follow this pattern

1. add `'APP_DIRS': True,` to your settings file.
2. go to your app and create this folders `templates/admin/model_name`
3. in this folder create file `change_list.html`

this links will help you.

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/
2. [How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)